# Spring Security - UserDetailsService implementation - Login Fails

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I'm quite new to spring and i'having this issue with spring security.
Actually it only works without my custom UserDetailsService implementation.

Account and Role Objects

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint (columnNames = "USERNAME"),      @UniqueConstraint (columnNames = "EMAIL")})
public class Account implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2872791921224905344L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="USERNAME")
@NotNull
private String username;

@Column(name="PASSWORD")
@NotNull
private String password;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
@NotNull
@Email
private String email;

@Column(name="ENABLED")
private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="ACCOUNT_ROLE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name="ID_ACCOUNT")}, inverseJoinColumns ={ @JoinColumn (name="ID_ROLE")})
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
```

Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLE", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint (columnNames="NAME")})
public class Role implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9162292216387180496L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
@NotNull
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>(0);
```

The adapter for the UserDetails

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "deprecation" })
public class UserDetailsAdapter implements UserDetails {

private Account account;

public UserDetailsAdapter(Account account) {this.account = account;}

public Account getAccount() {return account;}

public Integer getId(){return account.getId();}

public String getEmail () {return account.getEmail();}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (Role r :account.getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(r.getName()));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

The custom UserDetailsService

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Inject AccountDao accountDao;
@Inject RoleDao roleDao;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Account account= accountDao.findByUsername(username);



    if(account==null) {throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
    } else if (account.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " has no authorities");
                }
    UserDetailsAdapter user = new UserDetailsAdapter(account);
    return user;
    }
```

The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-  context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Creates the Filters to handle hibernate lazyload exception -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the root-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties"/> 
<!-- Remember to correctly locate the right file for properties configuration(example DB connection parameters) -->
<bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring.properties" />

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.treci">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <import resource="/appServlet/data-context.xml"/>
```

The security context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/resources" security="none" />


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login-success" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <form-login login-page="/login" 
    default-target-url="/login-success"
    authentication-failure-url="/login-failed"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="org.treci.app.service.CustomUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>


<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I hope some of you can help, save me :)

Comment: Do you have any logs? I have similar problem when my UserDetailsService was not @Transactional.

Comment: How exactly it is not working?

Comment: after giving username and password it brings me always to the     authentication-failure-url="/login-failed"/ 

Data access to the DB is working actually working cause i'm printing on a web page the job of the DAOs

Comment: @madhead - so you think i should annotate the service with "@Transactional" ; i'm going to try; for this solution i think i should put <tx:annotation-driven/> also in the security context..is this correct?

Comment: @madhead  i tested with "@Transactional" but it always gets me to the authentication-failure-url="/login-failed" .

Comment: You'd better show us the logs.

Comment: there's no error logs showing - I always land on the login failure page that tells the user to try again. 
I apologize If I' m missing something in your request; if so, may I ask you to give me some more hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

in the CustomDetailsService I was returning a UserDetails Object by using an Adapter as you can see.

Looking at some tutorial I realized that i should return an org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User Object.

Here's my new CustomDetailsService implementation:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Inject AccountDao accountDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Account account= accountDao.findByUsername(username);

    if(account==null) {throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
    } else if (account.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " has no authorities");
                }

    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User(
            account.getUsername(),
            account.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
            account.isEnabled(),
            accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(account.getRoles()));
    }

public List<String> getRolesAsList(Set<Role> roles) {
    List <String> rolesAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Role role : roles){
        rolesAsList.add(role.getName());
    }
    return rolesAsList;
}

public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}

public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRolesAsList(roles));
    return authList;
}

}
```

Comment: If you're using LDAP to authenticate, a database for roles authorization, and don't want to pass a password to UserDetailsService, you can pass a string (ie "LDAP") instead. It won't accept a null value.

Comment: So you are not using your UserDetailsAdapter class then ?